# Moment JS seemingly returning random date

Tags: react-native, momentjs

Moment JS is returning a random date.

I am trying to create a calendar in a react-native project. I created this loop to count back the days from today's date.  I have attached my console and tried to clearly show how I tried to debug this.

The subtract method seems not to recognise the loop and the i value seems to stay at 16.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[This is the code that is causing all the fuss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0B6.png)[This is the output in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOHZO.png)

Comment: In the future, add the code itself to the answer instead of a image link. This makes the answer more self-contained and easier for readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Moment.js, **moments are mutable. Clone the moment before performing date math**

https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/

You'll need to create a new moment instance or clone the existing one when performing operations like .add(), .subtract(), etc.

```
const moment = require("moment");

const today = moment();

// count back N days
const N = 3;
let i = 1;
let days = [];


// #1 - Create a new moment instance from today and add -i days
while (i <= N) {
  const day = moment(today).add(-i, "days");
  days.push(day);
  i++;
}

console.log("Approach #1");
console.log({ days });

// #2 - A moment is mutable. So we use add() to mutate today by -1 days each iteration, clone the instance, and push to array
i = 0;
days = [];
while (i < N) {
  const day = today.add(-1, "days").clone();
  days.push(day);
  i++;
}

console.log("Approach #2");
console.log({ days });
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I've now passed lastDate.date to moment() and it works a treat. That helps so much. Will now read up more on mutability.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Please select this as the answer to your question.